# Unknown error 524 with fuse

Tags: java, ls, fuse

I tried to make an "ls -l" command on a mounted directory with fuse, but I get this error message:

> Unknown error 524

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you Google for `Java "Unknown error 524"` you will find a few hits for this, and a few possible causes.  A common theme seems to be that you are doing something on a FUSE file system of some kind.  It often seems to be related to locking, though that doesn't appear to be the case here.

In general, it seems to be a limitation of the FUSE file system implementation you are using.

In this case, if you are getting the problem running `ls` as an external command from Java, it is unlikely to be Java's fault at all.  It will be something that the `ls` command is doing that is provoking the error.